# How to extract the two elements in Selenium(python)?

Tags: python, selenium

I need to extract all the "snail"s and "hello world"s under class 'm' and 'n'. 
m and n are repeated, but they have different "snail"s and "hello world"s.

[![below][1]][1] .

Answer (score 1):

You can use most of the available `find_element_by` methods to locate and element, here is a [list of them alongside with the docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

You could, for example, find the elements by their link text, since they are `<a>` tags:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('snail')
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Re: hello world')
```

or, since you mentioned XPaths, you could use [`.find_element_by_xpath`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath).

Answer (score 1):

Simply use xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'snail')]")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Re: hello world')]")
```

it may possible issue with quotes as i dont know python too much

Answer (score 1):

To extract the element with text **`"snail"`** you can use either of the following :

1. **`css_selector`** :

   ```
   elem1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href=qry.php?userid=snail]")
   ```
2. **`xpath`** :

   ```
   elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='qry.php?userid=snail']")
   ```
3. **`xpath`** (Multiple Attributes):

   ```
   elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='qry.php?userid=snail' and text()='snail']")
   ```

---

To extract the element with text **`"hello world"`** you can use either of the following :

1. **`css_selector`** :

   ```
   elem2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[con.php?bid=284&id=142707]")
   ```
2. **`xpath`** :

   ```
   elem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='con.php?bid=284&id=142707']")
   ```
3. **`xpath`** (Multiple Attributes):

   ```
   elem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='con.php?bid=284&id=142707' and contains(.,'hello world')]")
   ```