# How to switch to f3 in the figure (Selenium + Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How to switch to f3?[image: here]

How to know the current frame?

None of the commands below works:

```
driver.switch_to.frame('f3')
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//frameset[@name='viewfrm']"))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//frameset[@name='f3']"))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract the two elements in Selenium(python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47299851/how-to-extract-the-two-elements-in-seleniumpython)

Comment: what is the error that you get when you attempt your code above?

Comment: This question speaks about **multiple issues** without any **distinct Question**. e.g. `1`)How to switch to the frame? `2`)  Introduce the relation of the several frames. `3`) How to switch to f3? `4`) How to know the current frame? `5`) (Why) None of the commands below works? .

Comment: I don't see any element with `find_element_by_class_name('sgo')` as per your comment to @BreaksSoftware question. Am I missing something? It can help the SO volunteers if you can update the Question with a textual representation of the `HTML` instead of an image.

Comment: Do some debugging... print out all the `FRAME` tags at the start. Then switch into the one you need to and print them all out again. Repeat this process until you get to the one you want.

Comment: Switching to this frame is working just fine. I just tried it. What are you trying to do after you switch into it or why do you think it's not working?

Comment: Did you do what I suggested above about debugging and printing frames?

Answer (score 2):

Try to wait until required `frame` appears:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("f3"))
```

After `driver.switch_to_default_content()` you can handle in the same way frames "menu" and "toogle"

Comment: Did you switch to any other frames before switching to `"f3"`?

Comment: In this case you need to switch back from `"menu"` frame with `driver.switch_to_default_content()` to be able to switch to `"f3"`

Comment: @Anderson There is no difference. I revised my post and code is attached now.

Comment: What happens after `driver.find_element_by_class_name('sgo').click()`? Can you describe the sequence of actions you want to perform?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name("f3"))
```

Comment: @questionhang are u in another frame ?

Comment: the web page is generated by javascript, that's not the current code from the page

Comment: questionhang, the code in your comment does not point to f3 at all.  I suspect that @Andersson above is on the right track, that you need to switch_to_default_content() in all of the right places.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't mention what you are trying to do once you get into the frame but this code is working. It does what your code does in a slightly different way but then prints the last column from the resulting table.

```
driver.get("newsmth.net/frames.html") 
driver.switch_to_frame("menu") 
input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='board']")
input.clear()
input.send_keys("foodinfo\n")
driver.switch_to_default_content()
driver.switch_to_frame("f3")
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='main wide']//tr/td[5]")
for row in rows
    print row.text
```